# Background Service Location Changed Not Fired Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to retrieve the real-time location of the device, I had implement ILocationListener in my Service Class as I want this to run even after the app is in the background or closed I have referred - [this](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/BackgroundLocationDemo)
and it seems not working for me even if I change my device location the location change event is not fired

My Service Class with Implemented ILocationListener

```
 [Service]
public class LocationService : Service, ILocationListener
{
    public event EventHandler<LocationChangedEventArgs> LocationChanged = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<ProviderDisabledEventArgs> ProviderDisabled = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<ProviderEnabledEventArgs> ProviderEnabled = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged = delegate { };

    public LocationService() 
    {
    }

    // Set our location manager as the system location service
    protected LocationManager LocMgr = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService ("location") as LocationManager;

    readonly string logTag = "LocationService";
    IBinder binder;

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        base.OnCreate ();
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnCreate called in the Location Service");
    }

    // This gets called when StartService is called in our App class
    [Obsolete("deprecated in base class")]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand (Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "LocationService started");

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    // This gets called once, the first time any client bind to the Service
    // and returns an instance of the LocationServiceBinder. All future clients will
    // reuse the same instance of the binder
    public override IBinder OnBind (Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Client now bound to service");

        binder = new LocationServiceBinder (this);
        return binder;
    }

    // Handle location updates from the location manager
    public void StartLocationUpdates () 
    {
        //we can set different location criteria based on requirements for our app -
        //for example, we might want to preserve power, or get extreme accuracy
        var locationCriteria = new Criteria();

        locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement;
        locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.NoRequirement;

        // get provider: GPS, Network, etc.
        var locationProvider = LocMgr.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);
        Log.Debug (logTag, string.Format ("You are about to get location updates via {0}", locationProvider));

        // Get an initial fix on location
        LocMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 2000, 0, this);

        Log.Debug (logTag, "Now sending location updates");
    }

    public override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        base.OnDestroy ();
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Service has been terminated");

        // Stop getting updates from the location manager:
        LocMgr.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }
```

My Binder Class

```
public class LocationServiceBinder : Binder
{
    public LocationService Service
    {
        get { return this.service; }
    } protected LocationService service;

    public bool IsBound { get; set; }

    // constructor
    public LocationServiceBinder (LocationService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}


public class LocationServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    public event EventHandler<ServiceConnectedEventArgs> ServiceConnected = delegate {};

    public LocationServiceBinder Binder
    {
        get { return this.binder; }
        set { this.binder = value; }
    }
    protected LocationServiceBinder binder;

    public LocationServiceConnection (LocationServiceBinder binder)
    {
        if (binder != null) {
            this.binder = binder;
        }
    }

    // This gets called when a client tries to bind to the Service with an Intent and an 
    // instance of the ServiceConnection. The system will locate a binder associated with the 
    // running Service 
    public void OnServiceConnected (ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        // cast the binder located by the OS as our local binder subclass
        LocationServiceBinder serviceBinder = service as LocationServiceBinder;
        if (serviceBinder != null) {
            this.binder = serviceBinder;
            this.binder.IsBound = true;
            Log.Debug ( "ServiceConnection", "OnServiceConnected Called" );
            // raise the service connected event
            this.ServiceConnected(this, new ServiceConnectedEventArgs () { Binder = service } );

            // now that the Service is bound, we can start gathering some location data
            serviceBinder.Service.StartLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    // This will be called when the Service unbinds, or when the app crashes
    public void OnServiceDisconnected (ComponentName name)
    {
        this.binder.IsBound = false;
        Log.Debug ( "ServiceConnection", "Service unbound" );
    }
}



public class ServiceConnectedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public IBinder Binder { get; set; }
}
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    readonly string logTag = "MainActivity";

    // make our labels
    TextView latText;
    TextView longText;
    TextView altText;
    TextView speedText;
    TextView bearText;
    TextView accText;

    #region Lifecycle

    //Lifecycle stages
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnCreate: Location app is becoming active");

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // This event fires when the ServiceConnection lets the client (our App class) know that
        // the Service is connected. We use this event to start updating the UI with location
        // updates from the Service
        App.Current.LocationServiceConnected += (object sender, ServiceConnectedEventArgs e) => {
            Log.Debug (logTag, "ServiceConnected Event Raised");
            // notifies us of location changes from the system
            App.Current.LocationService.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
            //notifies us of user changes to the location provider (ie the user disables or enables GPS)
            App.Current.LocationService.ProviderDisabled += HandleProviderDisabled;
            App.Current.LocationService.ProviderEnabled += HandleProviderEnabled;
            // notifies us of the changing status of a provider (ie GPS no longer available)
            App.Current.LocationService.StatusChanged += HandleStatusChanged;
        };

        latText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lat);
        longText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.longx);
        altText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.alt);
        speedText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.speed);
        bearText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.bear);
        accText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.acc);

        altText.Text = "altitude";
        speedText.Text = "speed";
        bearText.Text = "bearing";
        accText.Text = "accuracy";

        // Start the location service:
        App.StartLocationService();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnPause: Location app is moving to background");
        base.OnPause();
    }


    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnResume: Location app is moving into foreground");
        base.OnResume();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "OnDestroy: Location app is becoming inactive");
        base.OnDestroy ();

        // Stop the location service:
        App.StopLocationService();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Android Location Service methods

    ///<summary>
    /// Updates UI with location data
    /// </summary>
    public void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Android.Locations.Location location = e.Location;
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Foreground updating");

        // these events are on a background thread, need to update on the UI thread
        RunOnUiThread (() => {
            latText.Text = String.Format ("Latitude: {0}", location.Latitude);
            longText.Text = String.Format ("Longitude: {0}", location.Longitude);
            altText.Text = String.Format ("Altitude: {0}", location.Altitude);
            speedText.Text = String.Format ("Speed: {0}", location.Speed);
            accText.Text = String.Format ("Accuracy: {0}", location.Accuracy);
            bearText.Text = String.Format ("Bearing: {0}", location.Bearing);
        });

    }

    public void HandleProviderDisabled(object sender, ProviderDisabledEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Location provider disabled event raised");
    }

    public void HandleProviderEnabled(object sender, ProviderEnabledEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Location provider enabled event raised");
    }

    public void HandleStatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug (logTag, "Location status changed, event raised");
    }

    #endregion

}
```

the above  `public void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e) {}`
never get fired on my device location change

Comment: How are you registering the listener (could you pls add code to post)?

Comment: i am working on the same sample i have provided the link above, please have a link

Comment: A minimal, complete, and verifiable example here, in your post, is preferred (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, thank you.

Comment: @sαmosΛris have edited the code please have a look

Comment: I downloaded and ran the example successfully (values would update with surprisingly high accuracy for very slight movements), but changed project's android version from the default 4.0.3 to 6.0 (for compile, minimum, and target). I also had to enable the location service, and grant permission for it (in the app's settings) on the target device (fine and coarse location permissions were already checked in project properties), otherwise a null exception would occur.

Comment: @sαmosΛris i am not able to rectify the problem i am running same solution, have done same thing said by you and my gps is also On still i am getting Null value at var locationProvider = LocMgr.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);

Comment: @sαmosΛris i am surprised it ran on my Genymotion Emulator, But location provide shows null on VIVO v6 and Moto G5s Plus